# Remove "JVM invocation command line" from glassfish logs

Tags: jakarta-ee, netbeans, glassfish, netbeans-8, glassfish-4.1

I've a remote glassfish 4.1 registered with netbeans 8.0.2 buy my glassfish logs are being filled up with a continuous repetitive output that looks something like this:

```
[2015-02-02T18:59:45.449+0000] [] [INFO] [NCLS-GFLAUNCHER-00005] 

[javax.enterprise.launcher] [tid: _ThreadID=1 _ThreadName=main] [timeMillis: 1422903585449] [levelValue: 800] [[
  JVM invocation command line:
/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/bin/java
-cp
/glassfish4/glassfish/modules/glassfish.jar
-Xdebug
-Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=9010
-XX:+UnlockDiagnosticVMOptions
-XX:MaxPermSize=192m
-XX:NewRatio=2
-Xmx512m
-client
-javaagent:/glassfish4/glassfish/lib/monitor/flashlight-agent.jar
-Dfelix.fileinstall.disableConfigSave=false
...
```

And are making really hard to read useful output in the middle of all that noise, why is it appearing? and why it doesn't when running it locally?

is there some way to disable or filter that specific log entry?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After searching all over found out that the daemon manager was trying to start it over and over because it was expected to stay on foreground. So this caused that each time the daemon manager tried to bring it back Glassfish reported it on its logs.

Specifically it's a docker container with the image phusion/baseimage.

Fixed it keeping Glassfish on the foreground adding `--verbose=true` to the `start-domain` command.